# Синхронизация между процессами и потоками

Tags: c#, многопоточность, .net, синхронизация

Подскажите, как организовать подоную синхронизацию? Судя по теоритическому материалу может помочь именованый мютекс, семафор или некоторые события. Попытался сделать, но до конца не понимаю как. Допустим у меня есть общедоступный ресурс (пусть таже очередь). Я хочу написать некий класс, для работы с этой очередью, который будет использоваться из разных процессов (на одной машине разумеется) и потоков. Получилось что-то такое:

```
public class Worker<T> where T : class
{
    private const string MUTEX_NAME = "SOME_UNIQUE_NAME";
    private Mutex mutex;

    private Queue<T> queue = new Queue<T>();

    public Worker()
    {
        try
        {
            mutex = Mutex.OpenExisting(MUTEX_NAME);
        }
        catch (WaitHandleCannotBeOpenedException ex)
        {
            mutex = new Mutex(false, MUTEX_NAME);
        }
    }

    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        // check if entity not null
        mutex.WaitOne();
        queue.Enqueue(entity);
        mutex.ReleaseMutex();
    }

    public T Get()
    {
        if (queue.Count == 0)
        {
            mutex.WaitOne();
        }
        mutex.ReleaseMutex();

        return queue.Dequeue();
    }
}
```

Понимаю, что это нерабочая чушь, но как довести до ума не соображу. Использовать предпологаю примерно следующим образом: один или несколько процессов, в рамках которых будет один или несколько потоков, которые будут добавлять в данную очередь данные и один процесс, в рамках которого будет один или несколько потоков, которые будут читать данные. Спасибо.

Comment: Меж процессная связь что из себя будет представлять?

Comment: Я написал чушь в своем вопросе, а именно работу с одной очередью из разных процессов. На самом деле у меня есть кеш-сервер, соединение с которым не потокобезопасно. Один процесс будет добавлять данные в этот кеш, другой читать и обновлять. Как синхронизировать обращение между двумя процессами к данному кешу?

Comment: То есть реализация consumer\producer только между процессами, которые работают на одной машине.

Comment: Синхронизировать обращения между процессами и не нужно. Они друг про друга знать не должны. А вот кеш-сервер должен синхронизировать доступ к данным уже. Процессы для него - клиенты, фактически семафора с одним разрешённым входом должно хватить.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду использовать один "клиент" для всех обращений к кешу? Можно ли в рамках моего наброска указать мне что нужно добавить\исправить, чтобы можно было использовать и такой подход?

Comment: Всё просто. Пусть сервер обрабатывает запросы от клиентов в одном потоке. Если _приём_ запросов асинхронный по отношению к обработке, вам понадобится producer/consumer на обработку запросов в обрабатывающем потоке (на сервере). В синхронном варианте даже этого не нужно.